Custom Liquid tags ({% liquid %}, {% section %}) not working with kalimatas/php-liquid library
I'm encountering errors while trying to implement Shopify-specific Liquid tags using the kalimatas/php-liquid library. Here's my setup:
// LiquidRenderer.php
class LiquidRenderer
{
    private $template;

    public function __construct($templatePath)
    {
        $this->template = new Template();
        Template::registerTag('liquid', LiquidTag::class);
        Template::registerTag('section', SectionTag::class);
        Template::registerTag('javascript', JavascriptTag::class);
    }
}

{% liquid
    assign product_title = product.title
    echo product_title
%}

{% section 'header' %}

I get the following error:
Unknown tag 'liquid'
Cannot parse 'section' tag arguments
I've tried implementing custom tag classes:
class LiquidTag extends \Liquid\Tag 
{
    public function render($context)
    {
        return $this->markup;
    }
}




